# Animation Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a progress bar animation which needs to animate from 0 to whatever percentage when the progress bar becomes visible within browser's viewport. Animation **should always happen** when element is scrolled into the view which means that scrolling it outside has to reset animation to start.

**Here's my non-working code:**

```js
var $animation_elements = $('.progressAnimation');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);
 
  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);
 
    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
        $element.animate({
            "width": (600 * $($element).data("percent")) / 100
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        $element.animate({
            "width": "0"
        }, 1000)
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

```css
 body{
            height:4000px;
            margin-top:800px;
        }
        .myContainer{
            width:1000px;
            margin:50px auto;
        }
        .myContainer .progressBackground{
            width:600px;
            height:40px;
            margin:0 auto 40px;
            background-color:#eaeaea;
        }
        .myContainer .progressAnimation{
            width:0;
            height:100%;
            background-color:#00f36d;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="myContainer">
        <div class="progressBackground">
            <div class="progressAnimation" data-percent="80">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progressBackground">
            <div class="progressAnimation" data-percent="60">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> ***Note:*** run code snippet in fullscreen.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Animation is not execute in viewport ?

Answer (score 1):

Animating using Javascript within scroll/resize event isn't really wise. Without throttling the event it is wiser to do something very simple.

I haven't delved into your code and why it doesn't work, but I've devised an example based on your code, but I'm doing animation using CSS (offloading animation off of browser process), and simply changing elements' state when it's different from what it should be. This means that I'm shrinking progress bar to 0 only when element goes off screen (and not every single time a scroll/resize event fires which is what you're doing) and animating progress bar when it comes on screen only when it's been off screen.

This is the code:

```
  var $animation_elements = $('.progressAnimation');

  $(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
    var viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    $animation_elements.each(function() {
     var $el = $(this);
     var position = this.getBoundingClientRect();

     if (position.top > viewportHeight || position.bottom < 0) {
        this.inView && $el.css({ width: 0 });
      this.inView = false;
     } else {
        !this.inView && $el.css({ width: 6 * $el.data("percent") });
      this.inView = true;
     }
    });
  });
```

As you can see I've also used as much vanilla Javascript as possible to make event handler as fast as possible.

And [here is a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj8kh4b5/1/).